# Google App Script Get Selected Image Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

Hi I would like to know if its possible to scale the size of an image in a spreadsheet via Google App Script.

Basically i would like to reduce the size an image so it fits in a cell nicely then simply click on the image to see it at a viewable size.

So far i cant even get the actual cell i've clicked on.

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getValue()

Only gives me the the last selected cell and not the cell of the image i actually clicked.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

When you do an Insert > Image, the image just sits on top of all the cells in the sheet and I don't think we can access it.

If your images are inside of cells as a result of using the `=Image()` spreadsheet formula, then sure you could control the re-sizing options by changing the formula with `.setFormula()`.

Comment: Ok, but how do I go about accessing the cell I just clicked on. GetActiveRange() only gives me the last highlighted cell, not the one I clicked on.

Comment: Are you clicking on a cell and then expecting a script to run or are you clicking on an image?  Your question mentioned you click an image, so how has it been placed in your sheet if that's the case?